# Asking for netbook recommendation

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking about getting a netbook as a supplement to my laptop, which would be my primary computer. I have some criteria for the netbook, but am not too fixated on brand or model. I browsed the netbook tag on SuperUser, and noticed a number of similar questions have been closed, indicating that SuperUser is not for shopping advice.

There are some number of questions with responses, but seem to be a bit old. I imagine the netbook market has changed some since then, so was poised to ask a question with my specific criteria. But if SuperUser is not the place for it, where should I go for feedback on my needs?

Comment: Follow @Sathya's advice and drop by on Super User **Chat**, there someone will be more than willing to help you out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in being hesitant in asking your question.  It is off-topic and would be closed, much like the others you have already found.  As for where to ask your question, we may not be able to help you.  You can look around over at http://stackexchange.com, but AFAIK there are no shopping recommendation sites there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can drop by Super User and ask for suggestions

Comment: @Sathya Isn't that at odds with the issue brought up in my question here?

Comment: I think @Sathya may mean SU **CHAT**.

Comment: @Grant - eh, I mean Super User chat, my mistake :P Drop by Super User Chat, and someone over there will help you :) http://chat.superuser.com

Comment: Well there is a recommendation site in the pipeline, I've requested for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20084/technology-recommendations for the exact same purpose so at least a some specific recommendations can be asked without them being off-topic.